# Select one xpath element based upon the position of another

Tags: xpath

I want to select one html element based upon the position of another using xpath. For example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            Col1
        </th>
        <th>
            Col2
        </th>
        <th>
            Col3
        </th>
        <th>
            Col4
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            Value1
        </td>
        <td>
            Value2
        </td>
        <td>
            Value3
        </td>
        <td>
            Value4
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

In this example I want the td which is in the same position in the collection of tds that the th with the contents Col2 is.

I can find the position of the th

```
//th[contains(.,'Col2')]
```

I want to avoid doing this

```
//td[2]
```

Is there any way I can link the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one possible way :

```
//td[
    position() = count(//th[contains(.,'Col2')]/preceding-sibling::th)+1
 ]
```

**<kbd>[`xpathtester demo`](http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/ef90a7d88d818b82e5521caf7fdf0777)</kbd>**

The XPath returns `td` at position equals to *position of the `th`*. *position of the `th`* is calculated by counting number of preceding sibling `th`, +1 since XPath position index starts from 1.